# Is there a way to finish the current activity with a button of an alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm having issues with the alert box that I've created. My intention was to restart or finish the activity of my Change Activity page by using the alert box. However, having `finish();` does not work and gives out a squiggly line error.

Is there a way to finish the current activity with a button of the alert box without errors?

CreateCancelDialog.java

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;

public class CreateCancelDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builderDialogCancel = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builderDialogCancel.setTitle("Confirm Cancellation");
        builderDialogCancel.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to return to the main screen?");
        builderDialogCancel.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                callMainPage();
            }
        }) .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });

        return builderDialogCancel.create();
    }

    private void callMainPage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GPIMainUI.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); //gives out squiggly line
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I do know that codes below work in a normal activity. BUT it does not work in the alert dialog.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChangePassword.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem... Webfreak gave me a clue on the solving part. Credits to Webfreak.

```
builderDialogCancel.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            callMainPage(getActivity());
        }
    })

private void callMainPage(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GPIMainUI.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)context).finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call:
`getActivity().finish();` instead of just `finish();`